# what is the most efficient data structure for matching specific numbers to ranges of percents?

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures

In my program, I want to be able to match certain numbers to ranges of percentages, like: 0 would be the match of 0%, 1 would be the match of less then 10%, 2 would be the match of 10%-20%... and so forth. What is the most efficient data structure/method to do it ?
I would like to perform it in c#.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what benchmarks have you performed? "Best" is subjective and is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: That sounds more like a formula than a data structure (`int number = percent / 10 + 1;`). How do you plan on using it?

Comment: Efficiency is defined as value produced per resource consumed. What value are you producing, and what resource are you consuming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dictionary for this purpose could be a decent solution. The keys of the Dictionary would be the numbers and the values could be Tuples with the corresponding min and max percentages. If you want to learn the range for a number you could retrieve it's range in O(1).

You could define it as:

```
var numbersPercentageRanges = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<double, double>>
{
    { 0, Tuple.Create(0,0) },
    { 1, Tuple.Create(0.1,0.2)}
};
```

and you could retrieve the corresponding range as:

```
if(numbersPercentageRanges.TryGetValue(1, out var range))
{
    var min = range.Item1;
    var max = range.Item2;
}
```

Comment: If the indexes can only be 0, 1, 2... then you may as well use an array.

Comment: Callum - the indexes are not 0, 1, 2 - they are marks, which can also be float or double. and the percentages come in ranges, so an array is not an option.